# Determine property changed

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a public class with properties. They can be changed by user and in some internal code. How an i determine if the property was changed by user ? Maybe there are some patterns for this task ?

It looks like i explaned my problem not clear enough.
I have a dll with public class that contains many properties.
User can set them.
Also they are set in internal code of my dll.
I need to create a mechanism to know, if that property was set by user or not.

Comment: what needs to know that it was changed by the user?

Comment: "By the external user" - you mean by other code using your class, vs. code inside of the class itself?

Comment: Daniel A. White: Another class will check if the properties were changed by user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to: Implement Property Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx). It's basically an example on implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

As pointed out by others the pattern of notifying others when something has happened is called the Observer Pattern. You should see this a lot in events handling code. Users of your class would sign up for notification by supplying a callback to be called when the event occurs (in your case, a change in the value of some property). In the example code, users of the class are notified whenever the PersonName property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern :).

You should use events. Have a look at [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Here is a little code snippet you should consider, it uses basic events to notify changement :

```
    Public Property EstMenage() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _estMenage
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _estMenage = value
            NotifyDataChanged()
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub NotifyDataChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent OnDataChanged(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub NotifyDataChanged()
        NotifyDataChanged(me, new EventArgs())
    End Sub

    <NonSerialized()> _
    Friend Event OnDataChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

Edit :

In the `setter` you could have some code that determines if the calling method is within the actual class or not. 
If the caller is in the class => Dont raise
Else, the caller is not in the class => Raise

Comment: In this code a notification will be made in both cases: when the property was changed by internal code or by external code.

Comment: Why not simply access directly your private member if you dont want to notify ? Thats what I do. Internally, you dont need to use the property, because you are working inside the class. Only other solution I see, is to use reflection to determine the calling method. If the calling method is not part of the actual class, then raise event. If it is, dont raise. But this will be a bit more costly

Comment: i change the property not in the same class it belongs.

Comment: Well then you can use reflection to determine from where the property is modified. But are you sure you dont have a design problem ? I find it quite weird :/

Comment: No, reflection can't be used, this is project rule.

Comment: What is strange with the properties? I have private fields and public properties.

Comment: Well without using reflection, there is no other, appart from using a private equivalent. You could access the private member directly, without using the property.
Edit what I find weird, is that you are using your public property from within your class. Shouldnt you be using the private field directly ?

Comment: i don't use the property and its private field within the class they belong. I call it only from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) and analyse what is calling the property. You can use [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) to get the information what is calling your function.

Comment: It's too complicated in my case

Comment: You spent feeling sore of the problem much more time then it costs to implement in any way;)